# Trying to make a modal dialog prompt using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a modal dialog prompt using bootstrap but when I click on my specific button I need to add the modal to but it doesn't work.

Below is my code for the modal section and below that is my button code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="Register/Login" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4>Register/Login</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>                  
        </div>
```

This is my button code:

```
<li><a href="#Register/Login" data-toggle="modal">Register/Login</a>
                </li>
```

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? Where is the button you added?

Comment: i am watching a youtube tutorial on how to create the modal promt and I have exactly the same code as he does but when he clicks his selected button it executes the modal promt whereas mine doesnt

Comment: https://youtu.be/49cMKsiSU1k?list=PL0qaQSYB_0TD-7tNkfMnJ0DCFJVjBNF8G this is the video and the actual modal tutorial starts at 1:55

Answer (score 0):

@JordanMitch226, just try to rename the id, replace the '/' to underscore, and of course, don't forget to load the boostrap.js and boostrap.css in your page.

Answer (score 0):

As said, change the ID of the modal to not have a `/`, include the bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css, and add a `data-target` to your button.

```
<li><a href="#" data-target="#RegisterLogin" data-toggle="modal">Register/Login</a></li>

<div class="modal fade" id="RegisterLogin" role="dialog">
    ...              
</div>
```

See my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2m4vxcxz/

See Bootstrap's Modal documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: thank you it is working now except for when the modal does appear when I click the needed button everything darkens even the part that is displaying the text is this normal, sorry if i don't use the correct technical names I'm new to web development

Comment: It's normal. You can add `data-backdrop="false"` to your button to get it to go away.

Comment: thank you Mike also could you please go to 2:56 of this video as this guy has got the darkening the way i would like it https://youtu.be/49cMKsiSU1k?list=PL0qaQSYB_0TD-7tNkfMnJ0DCFJVjBNF8G he has got the text area normal but the background darker?

Comment: My original answer, without setting `data-backdrop="false"` is what you want.

Comment: thank you but i have done that but it does not darken the background and just displays the modal popup.

Comment: i have sorted it all now thanks for all your help Mike but one last thing please when I click the close button on the dialog prompt the button that was pressed to display the prompt is highlighted blue?? sorry for being a pain